# How to View Big Pixel Images In flutter

Tags: image, flutter, imageview

I am new to flutter. i am trying to view this type of images in flutter. how can i do that
http://www.bigpixel.cn/t/374679393j837b3702ag8lkj

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package to open this type of image in the webview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

const _url = 'https://flutter.dev';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _launchURL,
              child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

void _launchURL() async =>
    await canLaunch(_url) ? await launch(_url) : throw 'Could not launch $_url';
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please put some examle code to do that

Comment: I have already tried this. this code is for open the image link in web browser. I want  to  Display this type of images without opening the web browser. Only from the flutter application. (For example: Google Map- in google map app we can zoom any place we want to see without using any other app or browser)

Comment: As this is not any image type format like jpg/png etc.., it's a kind of webpage which's why you cannot directly it on any flutter widget, you compulsory have to use webview for that. otherwise, flutter will throw on exception.

Comment: Thank you for your support. As i think this is not a one image. it is a collection of Lot of images. If it can display in web page why it can not using mobile application. If you found any method to do that in flutter or java please let me know